# Authenticated user on constructor

Tags: laravel-5.3

After research and watch over the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#5.3-session-in-constructors) and other links, i understand perfectly why this can't be done the "old way", but i really need a workaround/solution for this:

I have a base class, it's not called directly on the request (not declared on route):

```
class AdminPanelController extends Controller
{
    protected $_authUser;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
             $this->_authUser = Auth::guard('admin')->user();
             dd($this->_authUser); // ok
             return $next($request);
        });
    }
    ...
    protected function yoo() {
        dd($this->_authUser); // auth user is null, but i need this here
    }
}
```

I need for the authenticated user to be available on the `yoo()` method. The controller called directly:

```
Route::get('users', 'UsersController@hey');
```

UsersController:

```
class UsersController extends AdminPanelController 
{

    protected params;

    public function __construct(Request $request) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->params = $this->yoo(); // auth user is null, but i need this here
    }
    ...
}
```

Note that if i call the method `$this->yoo()` on another place instead of the constructor the user would be available

NOTE: i also tried `$request->user()` (`Authentication user provider [] is not defined.`) but since i have a multi auth system i have to provide a guard and tried $request->guard('admin')->user(), with the result being `Method guard does not exist.`

Comment: Why don't you use middleware to authenticate the user even before accessing your controller?

Comment: I am doing that, that is working great, the problem is not with the authentication itself @manniL

Comment: Ah, sure. Misread that, sorry! Have you tried to access the user via `$request->user()`?

Comment: Yeah, but i have a guard and it throws `Authentication user provider [] is not defined.` @manniL. Thanks

Comment: @manniL I added extra info to the question

Comment: When you access the controller, is the user logged in before?

Comment: Yes the middleware makes sure of that (not that on the question, the `RedirectIfAuthnticated` one). Quite frankly that on the question doesn't seen to help at all, just post it because it's on the docs tbh @manniL